# How to ship the new Slurm 7-pack efficiently

Tags: mathematics, geometry, tiling

The six-pack is a thing of the past. Beverages of the future will use the seven-pack format. But how will the mighty spacemen of the future manage to ship the Slurm seven-pack efficiently in rectangular space crates?

Below is a schematic of the seven-pack.  How can you completely fill a rectangle using seven-packs of this shape?  It's ok to turn a seven-pack upside down, giving you a mirror image of the below shape.  The arrangement requiring the smallest rectangular space crate wins.

[image]

Whimmy wham wham wozzle, dudes!

---

Stated simply, can you arrange an unlimited but finite number of the pictured shape and its mirror image so that they perfectly tessellate a rectangle?

Hint:

> Remember that since the rectangle contains an integer number of seven-packs then M x N must be a multiple of 7. Furthermore, since 7 is prime at least one of the two dimensions of the rectangle must be a multiple of 7.

Comment: Don't worry, you can leave overlaps in the pattern and the delivery boy will drink the extras.

Comment: I assume empty spaces are not allowed?

Comment: Both correct. I left the grid lines just to emphasize the dimensions of the shape. No empty spaces, no overlaps, no rearranging the position of the seventh can except, as I say, as a result of turning the whole seven-pack upside down. No funny business. Just a perfect n x m rectangular grid in which each space is occupied by exactly one can.

Comment: What about rotation? I assume that's allowed, but you have not explicitly said so.

Comment: Yes, rotation is fine.

Comment: If rotation is fine - is any rotation fine? If so, you need a single pack that's placed on the a length 3 side...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have a 14x14 (28 case) rectangle. It is completely symmetrical. Someone beat that.

[image: 28 Slurm]

Comment: This is, according to my sources, the smallest possible solution. Well done!

Comment: Nice.  Obviously at least one dimension needs to be a multiple of seven, and seven itself doesn't work.  I'd tried placing tiles for 14 but couldn't get a good pattern so I was going to try to investigate residues from 21 or 28.  Conceivably there may be a 21xN solution with less area than the 14x14 one.

Comment: The big thing was after placing four cases down on the bottom, i noticed that i could put a fifth that got me 14 and also was 90° off of the first one. Figured I'd try working the symmetry and after getting the edges done, the center just fell into place. After posting, i tried to shorten it to 14x10 or 14x8, but nothing was working. Guess i know why now.

Comment: Congratulations! What did you draw this with?

Comment: @Grantwalzer, My guess is "Excel\ Font section\ Draw Border" (that is alt H B W)

Comment: @Rafe Absolutely. Spolsky would be proud.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an alternate solution:

[image: Alternate solution]

A computer search revealed 96 solutions for a 14x14 square, and no smaller solution.

The 96 solutions break down into 3 alternate ways to arrange the 4 center pieces, x2 for clockwise/counterclockwise arrangement, and 4 pairs of 2 pieces that can be flipped.  That gives $3 * 2 * 2^4 = 96$ solutions.

Comment: Did you deliberately choose to break the rotational symmetry or was that an accident?

Comment: No.  I picked one solution from the 96 solutions I found.  I didn't look carefully, I though it was symmetrical.

Comment: 96? Yours differs from Joel Rondeau's in three of the four pairs going in from the middle of the edges (4x4 square with two opposite corners removed: two solutions, which are rotations of each other, so 2^4 = 16 configurations) and in the middle 4 blocks. Are there six configurations for the middle 4 blocks, or do you also have some which differ in the corners?

Comment: Answer updated.