# Packing an Efficient 9 Pack

Tags: geometry, tiling

This is sorta like [How to ship the new Slurm 7-pack efficiently](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/how-to-ship-the-new-slurm-7-pack-efficiently) by Matt Malone but instead of 7, it's the 9 pack! It's basically a 2 by 4 pack with a piece sticking out, like in the above link. What's the smallest version rectangle that you can make with the described shape, solution with the least packs gets best solution.

Comment: I think a square is slightly nicer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thihk this is the 6x6 solution
[image]

Comment: Wait, you **think** it's the 6x6? :P

Comment: @Joe Although it isn't, it looks smaller.

Answer (score 4):

Just 4 packs are needed (sorry if the picture is too tall): [image]

Comment: Nice! I'll give the others a few hours to find something smaller before I mark this as accepted (although I bet this is the smallest)

Comment: You can do a 6x6 square too, but it also uses 4.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can reason out why you can't beat 4

Comment: I would actually accept 6x6 first. Someone post it.

Comment: @Joel Post the 6x6

Comment: @warspyking Was away. Glad someone posted it. I originally wasn't going to simply because I could only tie and not beat JonTheMon's answer

Comment: @Joel The square, for some reason, appears smaller.