# Help me remember

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords

I seem to be getting more forgetful these days.
Today I can't remember my password to my super-secret Puzzling sock-puppet account.
I know I did that thing where you use the first letters of words of some phrase or whatever.
And I left myself a "password hint" - it follows the pattern **Xxxx:xxxx.XXX!**
(so there is upper-case, lower-case, and special characters, and the length is 14).
I just can't seem to remember what it *is*.

Fortunately, in a moment of foresight, I left myself a crossword that should remind me.
Unfortunately, I'm having trouble figuring that out too:
The clues aren't numbered, and don't seem to be in the right order at all.  Arrgh!

Maybe you can help?

[image]

#### ACROSS

May earn you +2 reputation
    Orange, kind of
    Endlessly talked or whined
    Recent puzzle, “Surviving the Zombie ___”
    For *puzzles*, not *problems*
    Endothermic, like birds and mammals
    Definitely out of this world
    Informally, “Vandy”

#### DOWN

Ta, W, Re, ...
    Foremost tag on Puzzling
    Stack _______
    Ravenous eater; lover of (too much) good food
    Name of a kind of pi(e)
    Often run-down, *very* cheap lodging; a dive
    Employer of Linus Torvalds in 2000
    Evidently, how “Slurm 7-packs” should be shipped

Comment: *for Kaylie* $\;$

Comment: Like we'll tell you your sock-puppet account password. ;)

Comment: To assist future solvers: 4 boxes: **15** 5 boxes: **14** 6 boxes: **6,8** 8 boxes : **1,7,9** 9 boxes: **2,3,12** 10 boxes: **5,11** 11 boxes: **4,10,11** 16 boxes: **13** 20 boxes: **16**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

The clues and answers:

> `4A: For puzzles, not problems                        - MATHEMATICS
>  5A: Recent puzzle, “Surviving the Zombie ___”        - APOCALYPSE
>  7A: Endlessly talked or whined                       - YAMMERED
> 11A: Endothermic, like birds and mammals              - WARMBLOODED
> 13A: Definitely out of this world                     - EXTRATERRESTRIAL
> 14A: Orange, kind of                                  - NAVEL
> 15A: May earn you +2 reputation                       - EDIT
> 16A: Informally, “Vandy”                              - VANDERBILT UNIVERSITY
>  
>  1D: Stack _______                                    - EXCHANGE
>  2D: Name of a kind of pi(e)                          - RASPBERRY
>  3D: Often run-down, very cheap lodging; a dive       - FLOPHOUSE
>  6D: Ta, W, Re, ...                                   - OSMIUM
>  8D: Foremost tag on Puzzling                         - RIDDLE
>  9D: Ravenous eater; lover of (too much) good food    - GOURMAND
> 10D: Evidently, how “Slurm 7-packs” should be shipped - EFFICIENTLY
> 12D: Employer of Linus Torvalds in 2000               - TRANSMETA`
>
>  4A is a reference to [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics), 2D is a reference to the Raspberry Pi microcomputer (as well as the food), 6D to elemental abbreviations, and 10D to [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/how-to-ship-the-new-slurm-7-pack-efficiently).

So we can see that

> the first letters of the answers spell "MAY WE NEVER FORGET", and the first letters of the clues spell "FREEDOM IS NOT FREE". These form an American idiom about the holiday of Memorial Day, which fits perfectly in the Xs. And confirming this is the letters at the intersections of the grid, which spell out HAPPY MEMORIAL DAY. Combining these and taking the first letters, the password is **`Mwnf:finf.HMD!`**

Comment: OK, I've got the hang of the spoilery stuff. Give me just a sec to work it out.

Comment: @Alconja ah, beat me to it :) I was just about to save my edit when yours rolled in.

Comment: @Brandon_J - sorry didn't realise you were already looking into it. For future reference to anyone reading, as of semi-recently, you can use [code fences to do blocks of formatted text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks/322000#322000) without needing four space indenting or <pre> tags, which makes it work in spoilers reasonably nicely.

Comment: @Alconja no hard feelings - thanks so much for the info!

Answer (score 0):

## Work in Progress (now pointless)

**Across**

A. May earn you +2 reputation

> Accepting (7)

B. Orange, kind of

C. Endlessly talked or whined

D. Recent puzzle, “Surviving the Zombie ___”

E. For puzzles, not problems

F. Endothermic, like birds and mammals

> Warm-blooded (4 or 11)

G. Definitely out of this world

H. Informally, “Vandy”

> Vanderbilt University (16)

**Down**

I. Ta, W, Re, ...

J. Foremost tag on Puzzling

> Riddle (6 or 8)

K. Stack _______

> Exchange (1 or 9)

J. Ravenous eater; lover of (too much) good food

K. Name of a kind of pi(e)

L. Often run-down, very cheap lodging; a dive

M. Employer of Linus Torvalds in 2000

> Linux (14)

N. Evidently, how “Slurm 7-packs” should be shipped

## Some grunt work and notes:

Words with 4 boxes: 15

5 boxes: 14

6 boxes: 6,8

8 boxes : 1,7,9

9 boxes: 2,3,12

10 boxes: 5,11

11 boxes: 4,10,11

16 boxes: 13

20 boxes: 16

***I am using letters for each of the clues so as not to confuse with the word slots in the crossword, which are numbered.***